# Update global variable after array number triggered

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I'm using Gamemaker Studio 2, and the asset [FC's Dialogue System](https://marketplace.yoyogames.com/assets/6076/fc-s-dialogue-system) as a base for the code that I'm currently working with.

This is the base code;
[image]

What I'm trying to do at the moment is that, when a certain message in the array is reached, a global variable is changed.

For example, when the player gets to Text(2) being drawn letter-by-letter onscreen, it changed the global variable global.kaifound to 20.

I've tried using if statements, like:

`if myText(2) { //change variable }`,

`if myText = 2 { //change variable}`,

`if message_current (Text(2)) { //change variable }`, etc,

but everything I've tried hasn't worked so far.

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how you're using your arrays or variables. But I assume `message_current` is used to pick a string out of the array. In that case you should use `[]` instead of `()`

```
if (message_current == myText[2])
{
    //change variable
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work... have any other ideas? :)

Comment: That's difficult to tell with the current source available, could you show more of the code? like the location where the variables are created?